# Arangodb AQL UPDATE for internal field of object

Tags: arangodb, aql, nosql

Given the following example document of collection:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1413543986,
  "message": "message",
  "readed": {
    "8": null,
    "9": null,
    "22": null
  },
  "type": "1014574149174"
}
```

How do I update the value of specific key in object with key "readed"? For example update value for key "8":

```
...
   "8": 10,
...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use MERGE or MERGE_RECURSIVE as follows:

```
db._query("FOR u IN test FILTER u._key == @key UPDATE u WITH
  'read': MERGE_RECURSIVE(u.read, { '8': 10 }) } IN test",
  { key: "11611344050" })
```

Merge will merge documents, where later values will overwrite earlier ones. See http://docs.arangodb.org/Aql/Functions.html for details.

Comment: I think it would make sense to expose this function in the collection.update method via another parameter like so: collection.update(document, data, overwrite, keepNull, waitForSync, mergeRecursive) as updating an inner field is a common use case.

Comment: Typo: shouldn't it be `WITH {
  'read': MERGE_RECURSIVE(u.read, { '8': 10 }) }`? (missing open `{`)